# access content made by js from a ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to load a page

```
$.get(url, function(content){
   //ajax content
});
```

on the main page I have my header file included that has global stylesheets and javascript libraries

I have the same include file in the 2nd page i'm loading in via ajax. Dependently these pages work great.

My JS is making html markup on the fly in the 2ns page, my problem is that when I load in the 2nd page into my main page the global JS isn't being applied to the 2nd page.

So now my markup isn't being generated.

How can I use an ajax call to also apply the JS being pulled?

My theory was that since the JS is being loaded when the DOM is ready maybe thats why i'm not able to have it load using AJAX?

Comment: You could use either [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or re-initialise upon `$.get()` success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your "global" javascript into a function, and then call that function every time ajax returns new content.

Comment: ya, thats why i fell back to. just didn't like my code to be all fragmented. but oh well. they need to fix how ajax works in the long run

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to make any assumption about your problem if you don't share some code. There might be more than one reason why your markup is not being generated the way you expect.

Comment: No, I remember now that content loaded by an ajax call won't get any js code applied to it when its loaded.